# What causes VLC to exit with 0 when I plug my laptop into an external display?

Tags: xorg, vlc

If I start VLC, then plug my laptop into an external monitor via VGA or HDMI, VLC exits normally.

If I then start VLC again, and unplug my laptop from the display, VLC again exits normally.

Probably, this is intended / known behaviour, and my guess is for performance reasons: 
We need to cache all of X from GPU into immediate RAM while we initialise the new display device but to minimise the risk of X and its children crashing horribly, VLC will be killed rather than preserved.

Is this a correct analysis? What causes VLC to exit?

Comment: Try to start VLC from a terminal, with -v2 and check if VLC gives you the causes.

Comment: It crashes with a `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`! @GiacomoCatenazzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely something simpler: VLC loses its connection to the X display.  If you start it from a terminal, it might be verbose enough to show the error which causes it to exit.

Comment: But why don't `cinnamon`, `gnome-terminal`, `google-chrome` and any other GUI application exit as well? VLC is the only program I know of that does this

Comment: Perhaps they don't care about errors, simply keep trying to reconnect :-)

Comment: Turns out it exits with SEGV -- this answer is probably right on.

Comment: In any case, I would report such bug to VLC.